# cocos2dx running exported Json from cocos studio into an animation

Tags: c++, json, animation, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to read/load an exported JSON and resources from CocosStudio(this is a tool to generate animations)
But when i try to load or read is seams that the isn't any class or function in order to load this file. I did a web research and all i found were deprecated code or external libraries etc..
thinks like:

```
auto animation animation =             extension::ccSkeletonAnimation::createWithFile("FILE.JSON","FILE.ATLAS");
animation->setPosition((x+y));
animation->setAnimation("a",true);
this->addChild(animation,0);
```

The code above is using an external tool similar to "cocosStudio", called "Spin"

Is it any that can provide some guidance on this...? or the proper class to set an animation a JSON file?
The cocos2dx version is 3.1
Thanks in advance!
Best regards!

Comment: Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code to import animation from cocostudio to visual studio 12

```
    cocostudio::Armature* armature;  
ArmatureDataManager::sharedArmatureDataManager()->addArmatureFileInfo("DemoPlayer0.png","DemoPlayer0.plist","DemoPlayer.ExportJson");
        armature = Armature::create("DemoPlayer");
        armature->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width * 0.8,visibleSize.height * 0.5));
        armature->getAnimation()->playByIndex(0);
        armature->setScale(0.25);
        this->addChild(armature);
```

Or you can check this code in help section of cocostudio.

```
//async loading export file
CCArmatureDataManager::sharedArmatureDataManager()->addArmatureFileInfo("Cowboy0.png","Cowboy0.plist","Cowboy.ExportJson");

//Creat armature by name
CCArmature *armature = CCArmature::create("Cowboy");

//play animation by animation index
armature->getAnimation()->playByIndex(0);

//Change Permissions
armature->setScale(0.5f);

//Set the armature position
armature->setPosition(200,300);

//add to the current scene
this->addChild(armature,2)
```

Good luck !